# Active transition when setting initial theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, astrojs

When switching between (for example) Blog anchor and Home anchor in dark mode in [my website](https://www.ferran.tech/en), **all the transitions are "executed"** just after `document.documentElement.dataset.theme = "dark"` if `localHost.theme == "dark"` runs when the any page loads. That happens [here](https://github.com/ferranJS/portfolio/blob/abc23f7e62a0be9b62801d78ae39f228b1646b12/src/layouts/Layout.astro#L164C13-L164C13).

This is not a desired behavior, but I cannot find a good way to make this behavior appear.

The site is built with Astro but that shouldn't be a problem.

It can be tested [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/ferranJS/portfolio). However, this problem only occurs in production, so you will have to `npm run build` and `npm run preview` right after.
Thank you very much in advance.